# Action Listener - Connecting from another File

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener

I don't know what to do in order to get the `ActionListener` to work with `AlarmCalc` and to show the results of when the alarm will go off. I am also in the process of removing the `JOptionPane` coding that ask for the time and displaying the `Alarm` time.

Thanks in advance for the help!

**MainP3**

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainP3
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException
{
  AlarmFrame frame = new AlarmFrame();
  frame.pack();
  frame.setTitle("Alarm Clock");
  frame.setSize(400, 250);
  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible(true);

new AlarmCalc();
}
}
```

**AlarmCalc**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AlarmCalc {


public AlarmCalc()
{

    // Current computer time
      Date dNow = new Date( );

      // Creating format
      SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");

      String userTime;

      // Asking user for the date and time
      userTime = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a date, time in military time:\n Example: 10/08/2013 12:00");
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");

      // Computing the computer time and user time to see when the alarm will end
      Date Current = null;
      Date User = null;

        try 
            {
            Current = dNow;
            User = format.parse(userTime);

                // Computing the time difference
                long diffTime = User.getTime() - Current.getTime();
                long diffSeconds = diffTime / 1000 % 60;
                long diffMinutes = diffTime / (60 * 1000) % 60;
                long diffHours = diffTime / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
                long diffDays = diffTime / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

                // Reporting when the alarm will hit
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,diffDays + " days, " + diffHours + " hours, " + diffMinutes 
                        + " minutes, " + diffSeconds + " seconds" );
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
}
```

**AlarmFrame**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class AlarmFrame extends JFrame
  {

    private JTextField jtfAlarmClock = new JTextField();
    private JButton jbtSetAlarm = new JButton("Set Alarm");

    public AlarmFrame ()
    {

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    //p1.add(new JLabel("Enter Time: "));
    p1.add(jtfAlarmClock);
    p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Enter a Time: "));

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    p2.add(jbtSetAlarm);

    add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    jbtSetAlarm.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Double.parseDouble(jtfAlarmClock.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples, you have three basic choices...

1. You copy the code for your AlarmCalc class to your AlarmFrame
2. You can call AlarmCalc, but that's not going to allow you to pass the required information to the class from the frame
3. You write a new method, which allows you to pass the time values from the main UI to it and make the required calculations and return the result so it can be displayed on the UI

Comment: I just need to display how much time is left (Like it is already in the JOptionPane. I don't want to redo the work that's already done as that's not required in this assignment or was asked to use JodaTime.

Comment: Okay, So, what's so hard about moving the code from one class to another?

Comment: The problem with calculating the difference between to dates/times, is that a day is not exactly 24 hours long, nor does it take into consideration things like day light savings, but that's a choice you have to make